# MySQL: Calculate a new column (converting days to week) to get weekly sales of products

Tags: mysql, datetime, group-by, case

My table `sales` in mysql looks like this:

```
ID             Date     Quantity
00000001    01/01/2017  5
00000002    02/01/2017  25
00000003    01/01/2017  2
00000001    04/01/2017  58
00000005    01/01/2017  8
00000001    10/01/2017  2
```

I want to get weekly sales (week1 in this case) of each product. Following is my query

```
SELECT ID, 
    IF (YEARWEEK(Date) = '201401', SUM(Quantity), NULL) AS WEEK1
FROM sales
GROUP BY ID
```

it returns the following error:

```
#1055 - Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'sales.registerDate' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

I have also used CASE statement but its not working fine for me.

```
SELECT ID, 
    CASE WHEN  (YEARWEEK(Date) = '201401' THEN SUM(Quantity) END AS WEEK1
FROM sales
GROUP BY ID
```

It returns error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'THEN SUM(Quantity) END) WEEK1
FROM sales
GROUP BY ID' at line 2
```

The expected result format is

```
   ID     week1
00000001    63
00000002    25
00000003    2
00000005    8
```

What will be correct approach to get the desired results ?

Comment: In the first `SELECT` have you tried to add `YEARWEEK(registerDate)` in the `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try summing the case statement, something like:

```
SELECT ID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN YEARWEEK(Date) = '201401' THEN Quantity END) AS WEEK1
FROM sales
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I would take out the case statement as it doesnt seem to be needed, you are just using it to select where YEARWEEK is '201401'. A simpler query might be:

```
SELECT
    ID
    , SUM(QUANTITY)
    , YEARWEEK(DATE) AS YEAR_WEEK
FROM 
    SALES 
WHERE 
    YEAR_WEEK = '201401'
GROUP BY
    ID
    , YEAR_WEEK
```